# Pros and cons of manual package installation ways: CTAN and tlpkg

Tags: packages, installing, tlmgr

I'd like to provide a semi-automatic way for installing packages for a platform that doesn't support Perl / tlmgr: web browser / WASM.

I found two ways of getting package sources of e.g. [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome):

1. https://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/fontawesome.tar.xz
2. https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome.zip

These files have different directory structures.

What are pros/cons of using each method? Is any of these recommended / more colloquial?

Comment: the second one is simply a zip of the ctan directory, so whatever layout the submitter chose to use, with the focus on browsing the ctan archive. The first one is the directory layout the texlive maintainers actually used in texlive so used in production.

Comment: the texlive packages will have a more consistent structure and are better suited for some automatic installation. You could also check the miktex packages https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages, they should be similar.

Comment: Please feel free to convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Both of them came at the same minute and both of them answer my question, so whoever does it first if you care to write an "answer", I'll accept :)